# RewriteCond doesn't match, while literally it should

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

The goal is to make redirect from

```
/Swiss+Military/something..
```

to

```
/Swiss+Military+Hanowa/something..
```

I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /Swiss+Military/(.*)
RewriteRule .* /Swiss+Military+Hanowa/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Rewrite log at level 9 reveals the following:

```
RewriteCond: input='/Swiss+Military/' pattern='/Swiss+Military/(.*)' => not-matched
```

I can't figure out why it is not matched..
Any ideas?

**SOLVED - need to escape + signs at the pattern** (how didn't I remind that myself)

**edit**
There is even better solution for this case (which I didn't put at the beginning because it didn't worked - of the same reason as the posted one) - just a single RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule /Swiss\+Military/ /Swiss+Military+Hanowa/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RewriteCond uses Perl syntax for the pattern. That means the the '+' in your pattern means "match 1 or more" (of the previous character). Try escaping the '+' in your pattern by putting a slash in front of it like this: '\+'.

Comment: Damn... As easy as apple pie.
I'm into PCRE for ages and didn't recognized that I have special character as a literal.

Thank you, **msdin**!